# How do merge two data frames in R with different number of rows In R based on a column but the repeated on should get combined in the same row

Tags: r

These are the 2 example data frames

```
s1=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4),sex=c("M","M,","F","F"))
s2=data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4),symp=c("cold","fever","headache","pain","cough","sneeze","cramps"))
```

I want to combine this in such a way that it looks like

```
s3=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4),sex=c("M","M,","F","F"), symp=c("cold,fever","headache,pain,cough","sneeze","cramps"))
```

Comment: Using `dplyr` you can do `s2 %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(symp=paste(symp, collapse=",")) %>% right_join(s1)`. Basically collapse the multiple symptoms to one row per ID, then do a traditional merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to simply join the data frames as usual and then use `group_by` with `mutate` like this

```
library(tidyverse)
s4 <- left_join(s1, s2, by = "id")
s5 <- 
  s4 |> 
  group_by(id, sex) |> 
  mutate(
    symp = paste0(symp, collapse = ",")
  ) |> 
  unique()
```

Note that you may have to replace the pipe `|>` with `%>%`.